# ios- thread 1 exc_bad_instruction error in app

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, sorting

I am writing an app to simulate the nba lottery. I have already written the codes to generate the random combinations, and assigned them to each team.

Here is my method to simulate the drawings and assign the draft positions to each team. standingsArray is an array of Team items of type ObjectWrapper, with values of name, seed, wins, losses, draft position exc... for each team. So basically what Im doing is I have 14 balls and randomly choose 4 balls, which constitute a combination (order doesn't matter). So essentially there are a total of 1001 total possible combinations, but one is thrown out. (you can ignore the first while loop because that is just there so that the thrown out combination isnt selected). A number of combinations is assigned to the 14 lottery teams based on record (250 for worst team, 199 for second worst exc...). The argument in my method standingsArray already has the number of possibilities assigned to each team. Next, I randomly pull 4 balls from the total possibilities, and the team with that combination gets the first pick. But because all the combinations for that team selected cant be chosen again for the second pick, I have to remove all of those combinations, but that is very complicated so instead, i make a new array called tempPossibilities which appends all the combinations for every team except the one just selected, which then allows me to generate a new combination to select from.

However, I am getting an error at this line `for j in 0...(standingsArray[i].possibilities?.count)!-1{` It says bad instruction error, and I cannot figure out why I am getting this error. And what else doesnt make sense is that the for loop works and the tempPossibilities array is fully populated with the correct amount of combinations (without the lottery team), even though the error happens at the for loop?
Code is below:  any help is appreciated, thank you, and sorry for the really long paragraph

```
 func setDraftPositions(var standingsArray: [Team])->[Team]{
    var lottery: [Team]=[]
    var totalPossibilities: [[Int]]=combosOfLength(14, m: 4)
    var tempPossibilities = []
    var rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(totalPossibilities.count)))
    var draw = totalPossibilities[rand]
    while (draw==(unused?.first)!) {
         rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(totalPossibilities.count)))
         draw = totalPossibilities[rand]
    }

    s: for x in 0...13{
       for a in 0...(standingsArray[x].possibilities?.count)!-1{
         if(draw==standingsArray[x].possibilities![a]){
            standingsArray[x].setDraftingPosition(1)
            standingsArray[x].isLottery=true;
            lottery.append(standingsArray[x])
            for i in 0...(standingsArray.count-1) {
                if(standingsArray[i].firstName != standingsArray[x].firstName!) {
                    for j in 0... (standingsArray[i].possibilities?.count)!-1{ //ERROR is happening here
                        tempPossibilities.append(standingsArray[i].possibilities![j])
                    }
                }
            }
            standingsArray.removeAtIndex(x)
            break s;
        }
        }

    }
```

(repeat this for the next 2 picks)

Comment: Try this `var someValue = standingsArray[x].possibilities?.count! - 1` and then add that value in loop like this: `for a in 0...someValue`. Just a random shot at this problem, try doing it and let me know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: When I do that, it says I cannot unwrap non optional type int, and makes me delete the exclamation mark and replace it with (standingsArray[x].possibilities?.count)!-1. Then, the line where someValue is defined is given the bad instruction error, so that didnt work

Comment: The issue is probably with the unwrapping. Check into your code if you can unwrap the values somewhere before adding it in the loop. Try printing out the values of `print((standingsArray[x].possibilities?.count)!)`.

Comment: I figured it out by debugging it. I forgot that only the first 14 teams had possibilities and it was looping through the whole standings so some had null, which is why it was crashing

Comment: Give your question an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for j in 0...(standingsArray[i].possibilities?.count)!-1{
```

should be written like this:

```
for j in 0...(standingsArray[i].possibilities?.count)! - 1{
```

it needs proper spacing.

Comment: that didnt work either, still getting the bad instruction error. my guess is it has something to do with unwrapping the optional value, but I really dont understand that stuff